# Массив классов в С++

Tags: ооп, массивы, классы, c++

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые эксперты. Я только встал на тропу войны с незнанием С++, поэтому прошу отнестись со снисхождением, если вопрос дурацкий.
  Суть проблемы следующая: класс "Изделие" может состоять из 1 или нескольких классов "СбЕдиница", и/или 1 или нескольких классов "Деталь". Класс "СбЕдиница", в свою очередь состоит из 1 или нескольких классов "Деталь". 
Первое что пришло на ум, создать, например, в классе "СбЕдиница" свойство-массив из классов "Деталь". Но эта идея у меня не удалась. Я чего то недомудрил, видимо, с конструкторами, сидел долго, а теперь вконец запутавшись, взываю к вашей помощи:   Как правильно организвовать массив классов. Если можно малюсенький примерчик бы.. )

Заранее благодарен за дельный совет )

Comment: @cppNoob Не забудьте принять (кликнув по галочке) лучший ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, вам потребуется довольно простая структура классов (весь этот прием называется агрегацией). Возникнут проблемы с понимаем, то пишите - уточню, отвечу.

```
class Деталь
{
};

class СбЕдиница
{
    Деталь* pДеталь;
    public:
    СбЕдиница(int n)
    {
        pДеталь = new Деталь[n];
    }
};

class Изделие
{
    Деталь* pДеталь;
    СбЕдиница* pСбЕдиница;
    public:
    Изделие(int nДет, int nСбЕд)
    {
        pДеталь = new Деталь[nДет];
        pСбЕдиница= new СбЕдиница[nСбЕд];
    }
};
```

Comment: Я именно это и имел ввиду :) Вложенность как у матрешек :)

Comment: огромное спасибо. теперь я понял. загвоздка была в
     pДеталь = new Деталь[n]; 
я это действие реализовал по методу "почесать левое ухо правой рукой пропустив руку между ног"   
еще раз огромное спасибо )

Comment: пожалуйста :)

Comment: структура <b>объектов</b> классов

Answer (score 0):

Так и в чём суть сложности? Ну так да, делаете у изделия приватный список сборочных единиц, а у сборочной единицы сделайте список деталей. Можно ещё просто массив использовать. Однако, не ясно, в чём суть проблемы..

Answer (score 0):

Думаю суть проблемы в том, каким образом сделать этот массив. Просто объявляете ссылку нужного типа и потом вручную выделяете память под сам массив. Т.е. например:

```
СбЕдиница *array;
```

(где СбЕдиница - название вашего класса).