# Возможность "постепенного" заполнения массива классов

Tags: ооп, массивы, классы, c++

Спасибо за быстрый и четкий ответ на мой [предыдущий вопрос.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81) Следующий вопрос такой:  [предложенное решение проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81) (если я все верно понял) подразумевает, что пользователь должен заведомо знать структуру всех железячек, которые ему нужно описать и при инициализации сборки тут же должен внести все составляющие. Это зачастую нереально. То есть, нужно дать возможность пользователю добавлять новые элементы в свойсто-массив после инициализации класса-сборки. Я тут написал что-то похожее, но оно мне не внушает доверия (хотя компилируется - уже хорошо), прокомментируйте, будьте добры, мои труды

```
class clPart { //деталь
public:
      int prtHeight;
      int prtWidth;
      int prtLength; 
}; 

class clUnit { //сборка
private:
    clPart* pPart;
    int prtCount; 
public: 
    clUnit() 
    { 
      prtCount=1;
      pPart = new clPart[prtCount]; 
    }
    void addPart(clPart*); 
}; 

void clUnit::addPart(clPart* Part){
     prtCount++;
     pPart = new clPart[prtCount];
     pPart=Part;  //вот это мне очень не нравится, мне кажется это ошибка   
};
```

Заранее благодарен за конструктивные комментарии без элементов троллинга и посыланий к Страуструпу и Шильду )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У этого кода очень много проблем :)

Например, когда вы делаете pPart = new clPart[ptrCount], у вас

1. создается непрерывный массив из `ptrCount` объектов типа `clPart`;
2. `pPart` меняет свое значение на адрес нового массива, при этом адрес старого массива теряется, итого налицо утечка памяти; не говоря уже про потерянные значения.

То есть вместо того, чтобы добавлять деталь, вы создаете заново массив из ptrCount деталей, теряя старый массив.

Эту задачу вам лучше решать с помощью STL, а именно, стандартного вектора `std::vector`. Это как раз то что вам нужно — массив переменной длины. То есть внутри clUnit у вас будет переменная.

```
std::vector<clPart> parts;
```

Добавлять новый элемент так: `parts.push_back(Part)`.

Обращаться к элементам вектора как и с C-подобными массивами: `parts[i]`.

И вы «нахаляву» получаете размер массива: `parts.size()`.

Более подробно про векторы можно почитать здесь: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ru/container/vector/start

Comment: поправочка: следует писать std::vector<clPart*> parts;

Comment: По-хорошему, да. Но я специально оставил объекты, а не указатели, чтобы не было проблем с неосвобожденной памятью.

Answer (score 1):

```
clUnit::clUnit()
{ 
  prtCount=0;
  pPart = 0; 
}
void clUnit::addPart(clPart* Part){
 // сначала копируем все элементы из "старого" массива в "новый"
 clPart* pNewPart = new clPart[++prtCount];
 for (int i=0; i<prtCount-1; ++i)
   pNewPart[i] = pPart[i];
 pNewPart[prtCount-1] = Part; // сохраняем в массиве новый элемент
 delete[] pPart;
 pPart = pNewPart; // подменяем старый массив на новый
}
};
```

В целом по коду должно быть понятно, что там происходит, добавлю, что все таки следует использовать std::vector для хранения указателей на clPart. Просто ради большей производительности и эффективности. Приведенный код не оптимален для случаев частого добавления новых элементов.

Comment: Его можно было сравнительно легко сделать оптимальным для этого случая, если не создавать новый массив и не копировать указатели при каждом добавлении.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m как предлагаешь добавить новый элемент к массиву с установленным размером?